# Bidirectional communication between node process and python subprocess

Tags: python, node.js, pipe, ipc

I hope you won't fire me for my question because it's been two days since I first started looking for an answer.

This is the problem:
A node process spawns a python process which remains open for a long time (waiting for user input multiple times)

Conditions to be met:

- Bidirectional communication: node sends different messages to python and python sends different messages to node
- I cannot destroy and spawn a python process every time I need to call python
- Python answers node when a message is received (yes, async python)
- I would really appreciate avoiding using a web socket since this will always rest as local (although my priority is getting it to work)
- I'm fine with using any combination of spawn/fork, or ipc/pipe as long as it works

What I tried:

```
const cp = require('child_process')

var child = cp.spawn('python', ['main.py'], {
    stdio: [null, null, null, 'ipc']
})

child.send({ message: "hi from node" })

child.on('message', function(message) {
    console.log('Received message...');
    console.log(message);
})
```

and on the python side:

```
import os
import json

# just necessary formatting
def serialize(string):
   string = { "message": string }
   return bytes(json.dumps(string) + "\n", "utf8")

message = "Hello from python"
os.write(3, serialize(message)) # write on IPC
```

What works in this implementation:

- The process is correctly spawned and the message from python arrives to node

Problems with this implementation:

- I couldn't find a way to get input in python from node aside from the first call (the generating one) by using arguments. This is the main point of why I'm writing here.

Hope I've been clear enough and good luck to anywone who wants to get into this!

Comment: “*I would really appreciate avoiding using a web socket since this will always rest as local*” Can you share how you arrived at the conclusion that using WebSockets would prevent you from running this locally…?

Comment: I didn't, but I found the implementations to be far more complicated than a process - subprocess structure. Though I would be really thankful if you could provide me a solution with a web socket